# How to Skip Ansible Host if member of a group

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am working on a playbook (for use in AWX) to handle some backend processing for one of our web apps.
One of the extra variables passed to the playbook via a REST call to AWX is used to pass the hosts
to the playbook

```
hosts: {{target}}
```

target can be a single server or a list of servers.
Question: how can I use patterns to skip a host if it is not a member of an inventory group
e.g if I want the playbook to skip a server if it's in the staging group in inventory
I have tried the following:

```
hosts: "{{target}}:!staging"
```

this only works if only one server is sent as target var, however it fails if called with a list.

Comment: What does your `target` looks like when you have multiple hosts?

Comment: @Benoit thanks for your answer. changing the list of hosts to use colons instead of commas worked.  I did update my playbook to replace the commas in the host  `hosts: "{{target|replace(',', ':')}}:!staging"`

Comment: Update: I simply had to change my delimiter to all colons or all commas  
This now works if my playbook is called with a list of servers separated by commas  
`{{ target }},!staging)`  
Thanks to @Benoit and @Zeitounator for your help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if you do use `:` as delimiter for your hosts and not `,`.

---

The syntax `host1:host2:host3:!staging` works, but `host1,host2,host3:!staging`, on the other hand, does generates a warning

> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host3:!staging

and this could well be the issue you are facing too.
<sup>*[The two syntaxes are documented here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns)*</sup>

Given the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
    host3:

  children:
    staging:
      hosts:
        host2:
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: host1:host2:host3:!staging
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname  }}"
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [host1:host2:host3:!staging] *********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "host3"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

And it gives the exact same recap when using the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ target }}:!staging"
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname  }}"
```

Run via:

```sh
ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventory.yml -e "target=host1:host2:host3"
```

Comment: It's absolutely not a bug: you either use coma or colon as a separator but you cannot mix both. Note that using coma everywhere fixes your issue as well (i.e. `{{ target }},!staging`), and that mixing delimiters the other way around breaks everything again (i.e. `{{target|replace(',', ':')}},!staging`)

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator I changed it all to use ',' (`{{ target }},!staging`)and that worked great